# How to properly check if specific fields are empty?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting data from the user using the input field.
Three of these fields are required, and the rest are not.

So in the onClick function, I have put a condition if the value is empty to show an error msg.

```
  const save = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    
    console.log("first name", firstName);
    console.log("last name", lastName);
    console.log("email", eMail);
    
    if (firstName === "") {
      console.log('first name empty')
      setErrorFirstName("This field is required");
    } else if (lastName === "") {
      console.log('last name empty')
      setErrorLastName("This field is required");
    } else if (eMail === "") {
      console.log('email empty')
      setErrorEmail("This field is required");
    } else {
      navigate("/home");
    }
```

Suppose the user enters his name, but not the last name and the email. The error message will be shown only for the last name, and not for email.
Also, if the first name, last name, and email are empty, the error message will show only the first name.

How can I make for all the empty fields, not just one?

Comment: Maybe you can create a list of error messages. In each of your if statement, you add the error message to the list, and at the end you create the final error message from all the elements of your list

Comment: Why not use [HTML client-side form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation)?

Comment: Don't use `else if` and just `if`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `else` before the `if` statement will ensure this condition will only be checked if the previous `if` is false. Therefore, you are preventing two false conditions to be checked at the same time.

You should avoid using `else if` in this case.

Here is a suggestion:

```
if (firstName === "") {
  console.log('first name empty')
  setErrorFirstName("This field is required");
} 
if (lastName === "") {
  console.log('last name empty')
  setErrorLastName("This field is required");
}
if (eMail === "") {
  console.log('email empty')
  setErrorEmail("This field is required");
} 
if (firstName !== "" && lastName !== "" && eMail !== "") {
  navigate("/home");
}
```